# C# Windows Service memory leak timer and ping

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, timer

I'm creating an application with an engine and an asp.net client interface. Currently I'm monitoring servers if they are reachable through ping. On every tick, the timer calls some classes and perform for every server in _evmComputerEntries an IsAlive (ping)

I have a timer (5 second interval for testing and troubleshooting)

```
Timer timer = new Timer(5000);
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
timer.Enabled = true;

public void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _BLComputerStatus.Open();
        foreach (evmComputerEntry evmComputerEntry in _evmComputerEntries)
        {
            //eventLogEVMON.WriteEntry(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            evmComputerStatus evmComputerStatus;
            if (IsAlive(evmComputerEntry.ComputerName))
            {
                evmComputerStatus = new evmComputerStatus(0, evmComputerEntry.ComputerEntryId, 1, DateTime.Now);
            }
            else
            {
                evmComputerStatus = new evmComputerStatus(0, evmComputerEntry.ComputerEntryId, 0, DateTime.Now);
            }
            _BLComputerStatus.InsertComputerStatusEntry(evmComputerStatus);
        }
        _BLComputerStatus.Close();
    }
```

Becaus I call an Open and Close function to open and close the SQL connection, I think there should not be a problem ?

This is the IsAlive function:

```
public bool IsAlive(string server)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
            options.DontFragment = true;
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            int timeout = 120;
            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(server, timeout, buffer, options);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                result = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

evmComputerStatus:

```
    private int computerStatusId, status;
    private string computerEntryId;
    private DateTime statusTime;

    public evmComputerStatus(int ComputerStatusId, string ComputerEntryId, int Status, DateTime StatusTime)
    {
        this.computerStatusId = ComputerStatusId;
        this.computerEntryId = ComputerEntryId;
        this.status = Status;
        this.statusTime = StatusTime;
    }
```

Comment: What appears to be the problem?

Comment: Show us what what the evmComputerStatus constructor does.

Comment: When I monitoring my service the memory keeps growing

Comment: Ping implements IDisposable. You should be disposing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dispose Ping

```
public bool IsAlive(string server)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            using (Ping pingSender = new Ping()) {
                PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
                options.DontFragment = true;
                string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                int timeout = 120;
                PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(server, timeout, buffer, options);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    result = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much this did allot and it was the ping that increased my memory but I think there is something else that slowly increases my memory. I'm going to search for this and come back if required.

Comment: @Andy- Slow memory increase does not always mean you have a memory leak because of the way garbage collection works. But it would be good to scour your code for other places where you create objects that implement IDisposable. This is especially the case since you are doing I/O, and many classes related to that do implement IDisposable.